# Why does STL Algorithm for_each call the destructor of my functor twice?

Tags: c++, foreach, destructor, functor, stl-algorithm

I was experimenting with the STL algorithms and more specific with the for_each function.
I tried a simple use case for concatenating a vector of strings. Note that this is probably not a good and/or efficient code. Take a look at the boost::algorithm::join function, if you really want to concatenate a vector of strings.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include "concatenator.h"

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
     vector<string> list;
     list.push_back("hello");
     list.push_back("world");
     list.push_back("!!!");
     Concatenator concatenator;
     for_each(list.begin(), list.end(), concatenator);
     cout << "result = " << concatenator.getResult() << endl;
}
```

The concatenator class is implemented as a regular functor.

concatenator.h:

```
#include <string>

class Concatenator {
    public:
        Concatenator();

        virtual ~Concatenator();

        void operator()(const std::string s);

        std::string getResult();
    private:
        std::string fResult;
};
```

concatenator.cpp:

```
#include "concatenator.h"
#include <iostream>

Concatenator::Concatenator() :
        fResult("") {
    }

Concatenator::~Concatenator(){
    std::cout << "concatenator destructor called " << std::endl;
}

void Concatenator::operator()(const std::string s) {
    std::cout << "concat " << s << " to " << this->fResult << std::endl;
    this->fResult += " " + s;
}

std::string Concatenator::getResult() {
    return this->fResult;
}
```

If you compile and run this program, you get the following output:

`concat hello to

concat world to  hello

concat !!! to  hello world

concatenator destructor called

concatenator destructor called

result =

concatenator destructor called`

**Can anybody explain why I can't extract the right result from the functor and why the destructor is called so many times.**

Comment: Actually, I am surprised it got called thrice and not twice. I would have expected NRVO to kick in here. Are you using Visual Studio in Debug mode ?

Comment: @Matthieu:  I don't think NRVO can apply here because the functor returned by `for_each` is initially a parameter (it has to be copied somewhere to go from being a parameter to being the return value, no?).  That said, I bet a really good compiler could elide the copy somehow, especially if the algorithm is expanded inline.  I just don't think it would be NRVO.  I could be wrong.

Comment: I've used the g++ compiler on Ubuntu and executed it command-line. Too simple experiment to use an IDE ;)

Answer (score 4):

`std::for_each` takes the functor object by value, not by reference.  It then returns it by value.  In other words, your original functor object never gets modified.  So you need to do:

```
concatenator = for_each(list.begin(), list.end(), concatenator);
```

Incidentally, pass-by-value necessarily creates a copy of the object, hence the extra destructor calls.

Comment: @Oli - does that really concatenate the strings into the result object?  I don't see how the intermediate result is carried forward.

Comment: @Steve: Yes, that works.  See http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/for_each.html: *"`for_each` returns the function object after it has been applied to each element."*

Comment: But without this modification, how is it possible that it tries to concatenate "!!!" to "hello world"? How can it remember "hello world" when each time a new functor object is constructed?

Comment: @Nico: A local copy of the functor object is created when you call `for_each`.  `for_each` then applies *this* local copy to each element, so its state gets updated.  It is this local object that is returned (which creates another copy).

Comment: @Nico: Add a `copy constructor` and `assignment operatorr` to you Concatenator class that prints out data each time it is copied. You will then see the object being copied into the algorith at the start then back out of the algorithm at the end.

Answer (score 3):

The function object is passed to `for_each` *by value* and returned by `for_each` *by value*, so three instances of `Concatenator` get created:

1. You create one instance using `Concatenator concatenator;`
2. You pass this object to `for_each` and it is copied because `for_each` takes it by value
3. `for_each` returns the functor by value, causing another copy to be created

Each of these three objects is destroyed, hence the destructor gets called three times.

Comment: glad you answered this, do you have any idea *why* the STL design is to pass functor by value rather than reference ?

Comment: @Matthieu:  I don't know of any official reason (and I don't see one in the SGI documentation).  Two thoughts:  First, like iterators, functors are expected to be cheap to copy (usually they are).  Second, you want to be able to pass a temporary object to an algorithm (e.g. `for_each(v.begin(), v.end(), Concatenator())`).  In order to do this while taking the functor by reference, you'd have to take it by const reference, which means that the `operator()` overload would have to be const-qualified.  This is undesirable since you want to be able to have stateful functors.

Answer (score 1):

When you implement a destructor, it's likely that you *also* need to implement a copy constructor and copy assignment operator. This is known as the [rule of three](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_%28C%2B%2B_programming%29).

Once you correctly implement those two methods, then you'll see that it's not calling the destructor twice, but instead it's making a copy and destructing each of the copies.

Answer (score 1):

Other answers already explained to you that the problem in your case is functor object being passed to `for_each` and returned from `for_each` *by value*.

However, while it is true that the declaration of `for_each` is responsible for this behavior, the final word is said by the template argument deduction mechanism of C++. In accordance with the rules of the language, in this call

```
for_each(list.begin(), list.end(), concatenator);
```

the second argument of `for_each` template is deduced as `Concatenator` and not as `Concatenator &`, resulting in pass-by-value semantics.

You can override the deduction by specifying template arguments explicitly, insisting on the reference type for the second template argument

```
for_each<vector<string>::iterator, Concatenator &>(ist.begin(), list.end(),
    concatenator);
```

This will completely eliminate the copying and replace the pass-by_value semantics with pass-by-reference semantics (also covering the return value of `for_each`). It doesn't look as elegant, especially because functor type happens to be the *second* template argument, but it is a workaround.

Answer (score 0):

`for_each` takes the functor *by value* and returns a copy of it as the return value, so it's not your `concatenator` that is modified, but the one local to the `for_each` function that is then returned. You should change your code to something like that:

```
 Concatenator concatenator;
 concatenator = for_each(list.begin(), list.end(), concatenator);
```

In `concatenator` now you'll have your modified functor.

About the destructor calls: they begin when `for_each` returns; the first one is the one of the parameter of `for_each`, the second one is the one of its copy returned by `for_each` (which is discarded), the third one is the one of the original `concatenator` object, which is destructed when the program ends.